# C# - MessageBox - Message localization in resources and lines breaks

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, embedded-resource, messagebox

I would like to show MessageBox (WinForms) with string from Resources with lines breaks.

example **without** Resources (WORKS):

```
string someMsg = "Message. Details:\n" + someDetails;

MessageBox.Show(someMsg);
```

Result:

Message. Details:

here are some details

When I move string *"Message. Details:\n"* into Resources:

```
string someMsg = GlobalStrings.MsgBoxJustTest + someDetails;
MessageBox.Show(someMsg);
```

Result:

Message. Details:\nhere are some details

When I moved string with "\n" to resources then MessageBox.Show() stopped to interpret it as newline.

Edit: I'm thinking about: someMsg.Replace(@'\n',Environment.NewLine);
but it's still quite annoying for so simple thing.

Comment: related but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357804/string-replace-on-escape-characters

Comment: I don't wnat to handle this in code by Replace method or editing. I would like to add this resource file to "ordinary" user who can translate it easly.

Comment: right, but surely the "ordinary" user will find it more natural to put actual linebreaks in the right places, than keeping "\n" placeholders? (see @Chilaka Umesh's comment to his answer). Maybe the question is: How are you "moving" these strings to resource files? This moving process is where the \n should be replaced with an actual linebreak.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you add that to resources it doesn't take \n as escape charecter
Just open your resource file in notepad to see this and cahnge in XML file(resx)

or

Type your data in notepad with new line.
Copy that and paste in your resource editor

edit:

or

Type/Paste your data into the resource editor UI, select the \n and replace it with an actual linebreak, with `Shift-Enter`.

Comment: I see.. but I would like to have it automatic and as simply as possible.

Comment: In resource editor type "Message. Details:" then press "shift+enter" insted of just enter key. This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (as long as your **not** .net 2.0):

```
public static class StringExt
{
  public static String FixNewLines(this String str)
  {
    return str.Replace(@'\n',Environment.NewLine);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
string someMsg = GlobalStrings.MsgBoxJustTest + someDetails;
MessageBox.Show(someMsg.FixNewLines());
```

However, this will affect **ALL** strings in your application (namespace scope)

It's a dirty fix, but it's a quick fix.

Personally, I would just fix my logic all the way through, rather than do something like the above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can Open the resx file as code and add the line breaks directly in the
XML

OR

Possibly they get lost when reading due to escape character maybe try using `\\`

Comment: thx, but I don't wanna to switch from code->Resources->Resources code editing.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to store “placeholders” in a resource strings. For instane, this string is stored in *.resx under “MessageDetails” key: "Message. Details:{0}{1}". Then, in your code, use it like this:

MessageBox.Show(String.Format(GlobalStrings.MessageDetails, Environment.NewLine, @"The message"));

The advantage here is a portability, as you can see.