# String.Replace not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following problem with String.Replace:

```
string str = "0˄0";
str = str.Replace("˄", "&&");
```

when I print out str, it will be "0&0" instead of "0&&0". To get "0&&0", I have to write

```
str = str.Replace("˄", "&&&&");
```

Why is that?

Comment: Do you happen to be displaying that string in a WinForms or WPF application?

Comment: It works for me. How are you printing it out?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: && isn't one character, it's two - and `&` isn't special in string literals.

Comment: I'd like to display it on a WinForm label.

Comment: You've specified some special Unicode symbol `^` with hex code 0x3F but standard `^` has code `0x5E`, which encoding are you using?

Comment: are you wanting to display an underline if so replace it with a single &

Comment: Ever heard of [escape characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357804/string-replace-on-escape-characters)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Label property to accept escape sequences in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324310/label-property-to-accept-escape-sequences-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out this post:
http://moiashvin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/05/escape-ampersand-character-in-c.html

Labels are handled differently in WinForms.  You should be able to do as the post suggests and set the UseMnemonic property to false, see if that works.

Answer (score 6):

`&` is a special character in WinForms, used to indicate keyboard shortcuts. Using `&&` is how WinForms escapes the `&` symbol.

So, to display it in WinForms you are **necessarily** going to have to place **two** `&` characters in your string as you have here:

```
str = str.Replace("˄", "&&&&");
```

This is strictly a WinForms "thing" and has nothing to do with a C# or .NET string escaping specifically. It has been this way at least as far back as Visual Basic 4 - probably before then.

Comment: This is how it works in Win32. All of the various wrappers around Win32 (VB 4, WinForms, etc.) have just inherited that behavior.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the first comment - '&' is a special character for WinForms (and the underlying Win32 API) which is/was used to indicate a shortcut character for menu/dialog items.

'&' in strings means nothing special to C#, but if you want to put it on a form/dialog label, then you need to escape the '&' by adding another one in front.

Personally, I would get the string how I really wanted it in my 'business logic' first, then escape the '&' characters as part of displaying the string on the form.